# Picasso : Image is not loading in 5.1.1 but does loads in 4.2.1

Tags: android, url, picasso

I am using picasso library for loading images in my app. It is working fine in android version less than 5.1.1, but not in the 5.1.1.
Here is the sample url which is not loading
[http://sexocomcafe1-teste.tempsite.ws/imagensUsuario13/avata/Atração%20PerigosaRJ_44690132.jpg](http://sexocomcafe1-teste.tempsite.ws/imagensUsuario13/avata/Atra%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20PerigosaRJ_44690132.jpg)
This url loads perfectly in andriod 4.2.1 and others , but not in my 5.1.1 device.
Here is the code i have tried

```
//Singleton instance of picasso
 getPicassoInstance(){
 if (picasso == null) {
            picasso = new Picasso.Builder(PreferenceHelper.getContext()).executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                    .build();
        }
        return picasso;
}

getPicassoInstance().load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                        .into(myImageView);

Also following code by using the Target
Target targetAppLogo = new Target() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
                    Logger.error("on prepare load avatar");
                }

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                    Logger.error("Save aavatar success ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
                    Logger.error("Bitmap loading failed ");
                }
            };

            getPicassoInstance().load(url).into(targetAppLogo);
```

Above code gives bitmap download success for 4.2.1 and gives bitmap loading failed for 5.1.1.

I have no clue what is going wrong with the code.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are there any messages in LogCat, besides whatever `Logger.error()` does? Picasso logs some of their own messages, IIRC.

Comment: No there are no logs got printed

Answer (score 0):

Use **Html.fromHtml(String) method**. This should resolve your issue.

Add following line before load the image:

```
url = Html.fromHtml(url).toString();
```

So it will look like:

```
url = Html.fromHtml(url).toString();

getPicassoInstance().load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                        .into(myImageView);
```

Following is my sample code to load your provided URL image:

```
    String url = Html.fromHtml("http://sexocomcafe1-teste.tempsite.ws/imagensUsuario13/avata/Atra%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20PerigosaRJ_44690132.jpg").toString();
    Picasso.with(this)
   .load(url)
   .into(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquery is also using for image loading, download aquery jar and import it in your project and try this way

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView img;
    private AQuery aq;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aq = new AQuery(this);
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.simpleLoadImg);
        aq.id(R.id.simpleLoadImg).image("http://sexocomcafe1-teste.tempsite.ws/imagensUsuario13/avata/Atra%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20PerigosaRJ_44690132.jpg",false,false);

    }


}
```

Comment: if its working then why you compulsary want to use picasso only.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find solution, please check the below thing in your android code

```
 final boolean[] isImageLoad = {false};
 String finalUrl = url;
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           while (!isImageLoad[0]) {
               Picasso.get().load(finalUrl).into(new Target() {
                   @Override
                   public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "store image url onBitmapLoaded ");
                        heatMap.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), bitmap));
                        isImageLoad[0] = true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "store image url " + e.getMessage());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "store image url onPrepareLoad ");
                            isImageLoad[0] = false;
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }, 100);
```

Happy Coding!!